# How to compute the value of an infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, power-series

How do I compute this series$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{4}{n^2 - 4}$$
I know I should consider the k-th partial sum, which is
$$\sum_{n=3}^{k}\frac{1}{2n - 8}-\frac{1}{2n+8}$$
By observing which terms cancel and do not, the terms that don't cancel add up to $\frac{29}{40}$, but I do not know how to then determine the limit as k tends to infinity.

Comment: If the value you obtained doesn't depend on $k$, then you already know the limit, don't you. Though I'm afraid the series is equal to $25/12$, which means you might have made an algebraic mistake somewhere

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition is $\frac1{n-2}- \frac1{n+2}$ Please make a check of your calculation.

Comment: I recommend using http://www.wolframalpha.com to check your results for such problems. In particular, this series can be checked by the following code: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B4%2F(n%5E2-4),%7Bn,3,Infinity%7D%5D

Comment: I see, the partial fraction was wrong. Thanks for that. Do you know how I could get to this answer of 25/12? Rather than inputting into WolframAlpha, but the method.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that :$\dfrac{4}{n^2-4}=\dfrac{1}{n-2} - \dfrac{1}{n+2} = \left(\dfrac{1}{n-2} - \dfrac{1}{n-1}\right)+ \left(\dfrac{1}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1} - \dfrac{1}{n+2}\right)$, and use telescope for the $4$ sums.

Comment: What do you mean use telescope? I assume that is a technique, but what is the technique?

Comment: @M.Calculator, it's the same method you used in your attempt, namely telescoping is just "observing which terms cancel and which do not"

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac4{n^2-4}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac4{(n+2)(n-2)}$$
you could then use partial fractions to split this up into two harmonic sums with limits, then add them together

Comment: I thought harmonic sums don't have limits, whereas this summation does?

Comment: Yes the harmonic series is non convergent to infinity, but if there is a way to evaluate it for a known upper limit a dummy variable could be used to combine the two summations. However, this is just an alternative and I think your shown method is the best way of doing it